# Make an equation satisfying the data given

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

\begin{array}{c|lcr}
x & y\\
\hline
1 & 20\\
2 & 16\\
3 & 13\\
4 & 11\\
5 & 10
\end{array}

How do you start a solution when you have these type of problem? I was used to given an equation but not like all just numbers. It was state that the answer is $y=\frac{1}{2}x^2$ -$\frac{11}{2}x$ $+25$ how do you even generate that?

Comment: I;m not sure, since if I do interpolation I won't arrive with an x^2 and x

Comment: I have the answer, but a parabola I'm not sure on how to formulate the solution first so basically I can't start solving

Answer (score 2):

Since you have found out that it's a parabola (even if you've only guessed). Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Then, any $3$ points not all colinear will determine a unique parabola. So, try some of the points and you'll be able to solve for $a,b,c$. If the $6$ points don't all satisfy the equation, then it won't actually be a parabola: \begin{align*}
f(1)=20=a+b+c\\
f(2)=16=4a+2b+c\\
f(3)=13=9a+3b+c
\end{align*}
So, we need to solve this system of equations. You can do this with just algebra or matrix row operations, etc. Eventually, you should get $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=-\frac{11}{2}$ and $c=25$ so that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{11}{2}x+25$. To see if this is the actual curve wanted, test all of the other points given (they do in this case).

Answer (score 1):

We can use a [*Least Squares*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) fit and will use the example on page $3$ of these [*notes*](https://math.la.asu.edu/~checkman/242/242LN1.6_5.3.pdf) as a guide. We setup the system of equations to fit a parabola $a x^2 + b x + c$ as

$$\begin {align}
a(1)^2 + b(1) + c &= 20 \\
a(2)^2 + b(2) + c &= 16 \\
a(3)^2 + b(3) + c &= 13 \\
a(4)^2 + b(4) + c &= 11 \\
a(5)^2 + b(5) + c &= 10 \\
\end {align}$$

This gives us

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 4 & 2 & 1 \\ 9 & 3 & 1 \\ 16 & 4 & 1 \\ 25 & 5 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, ~~b = \begin{bmatrix}
20 \\ 16 \\ 13 \\ 11 \\ 10 \end{bmatrix}$$

Using Least Squares, we have

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}= (A^T A)^{-1} A^T ~ b = \begin{bmatrix}~~~\dfrac{1}{2} \\ -\dfrac{11}{2} \\ ~~~25 \end{bmatrix}$$

So, the final result is

$$y = \dfrac{1}{2}x^2 -\dfrac{11}{2}x + 25$$

If the theory is not clear, you can refer to these [*notes*](http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat419/lecture13.pdf) and look at another example starting on page $5$.